# Take Lat and Long from MyLocationOverlay?

Tags: android, geolocation, mylocationoverlay

I can see where I am via `MyLocationOverlay`, but I want use `MapController.setCenter(geopoint)` to take latitude and longitude of the place where I am.

Also is possible to take the upper left corner and bottom right corner coordinates of the screen?

Any suggestions? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Would [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) help? You'll set up you location getter in the *onLocationChanged(Location)* method.

Comment: thank you but I've already tried and I have " Couldn't get connection factory client" problem

Comment: Do you have permission to access fine grained location (i think this one is needed here) ? Edit: would [this](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/harolee/archive/2009/01/08/android-how-to-use-mylocationoverlay-to-find-where-i-am.aspx) help?